# Show Hide Div based on JSON response

Tags: jquery

I have two divs - divOne and divTwo.

divOne is always visible while divTwo is hidden.

Now I am reading a JSON service which returns the following data:

```
{"ip":"xx.xx.xxx.xxx","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"MI","region_name":"Michigan","city":"Lansing","zipcode":"48917","latitude":42.7257,"longitude":-84.636,"metro_code":"551","area_code":"517"}
```

I want to read the country_code and if it is "IN" then hide divOne and display divTwo.

How do i do it? This is what I have so far in jQuery 1.11:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var locAPI = "";
  $.getJSON( locAPI)
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, y) {

        }
      });
    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
(function() {
  var locAPI = "";
  $.getJSON( locAPI)
    .done(function( data ) {
     if (data.country_code == 'IN'){
      $('#div1_id').hide();
      $('#div2_id').show();
     }
      });
    });
})();
</script>
```

Country code will be accessible by `data.country_code`

Answer (score 0):

`country_code` can be accessed directly

```
if (data.country_code == 'IN'){
    divOne.hide();
    divTwo.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/3vd88m69/) with both code and data to illustrate the answer.

The solution is to loop through the `data.items` array and if the `country_code` is equal to "IN" then hide divOne and show divTwo.  This can be achieved using the jQuery [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) methods.

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, item) {
    if (item.country_code === "IN") {
        $("#divOne").hide();
        $("#divTwo").show();
    }
});
```

(Note: This logic assumes you are getting back an array of items where your JSON fragment represents an example of one item).